# R: find all observations from data.table with values from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables in R: `DT1` having about 30K obervations of 5 variables: `userID`, `userName`, `productID`, `productName`, `usersRate`, `DT2` having only 500 observations of 2 variables: `productID`, `similarProductID`. I want to find all rows from `DT1` which `productID` is same as `similarProductID` from DT2. I've tried `DT1[which(DT1$productID==DT2$similarProductID)]` and `DT1[which(DT1$productID==intersect(DT1$productID,DT2$similarProductID))]` but it didn't worked out, I receive too few observations. Any ideas how could I do this?

Comment: As always we need a reproducible example. But it reads like you should do a join.

Answer (score 4):

Fastest way is with a join:

```
#mock data
DT1<-data.table(userID=1:30000,userName=sample(LETTERS,30000,T),productID=30001:60000,productName=sample(LETTERS,30000,T),userRate=runif(30000))
DT2<-data.table(productID=1:500,similarProductId=sample(30001:60000,500))

#set keys
setkey(DT1,productID)
setkey(DT2,similarProductId)

#join
DT1[DT2]

   productID userID userName productName   userRate productID.1
1:     30014     14        L           R 0.87649196         473
2:     30025     25        E           A 0.02237395         326
3:     30027     27        H           Z 0.43986360         198
4:     30065     65        V           K 0.33047666         240
5:     30123    123        R           X 0.38637559         210
---                                                             
  496:     59575  29575        U           A 0.41036652         214
497:     59665  29665        C           E 0.67345907          45
498:     59724  29724        F           Y 0.18853101          81
499:     59764  29764        D           X 0.50271854         386
500:     59790  29790        Z           A 0.02222698         397
```

Comment: I get NA values in `DT1` by doing a join, is there may be a problem if objects have different types? Also `userID` and `productID` values aren't unique in `DT1`, every line in `DT1` is uniquely defined by both `userID` and `productID`. I need to get all the lines where `DT1$productID==DT2$similarProductID`.

Comment: `DT1[which(DT1$productID==x)]` works perfectly for specific x from `DT2$similarProductID`, but when I want all possible `DT2$similarProductID` it doesn't work the right way. My goal is to find all users who have rated similar products.

Comment: @v_toria, try using the `nomatch=0L` parameter. `NA` means that there's no match for the value of key in `DT2` in `DT1`. So try `DT1[DT2, nomatch=0L`. This'll only provide those where key in `DT2` is also found in `DT1`. HTH.

Comment: hi @v_toria - yes the `DT1[DT2, nomatch=0L]` example should work

Comment: Thanks @Arun, now it woks much better but the result is still not acceptable. I know that `length(intersect(DT1$productID,DT2$similarProductID))` is equal to 223 so `DT1[DT2, nomatch=0L]` should return data.table containing 223 different `productID`s but what subset that I got has only 63 observatons and number of unique `productID`s is 2 not 223. I don't understand why this occurs, can anybody explain me?

Comment: can't do much without a reproducible example of the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this way would be faster than Troy's join answer, but you can use the merge function in R.

```
  DT1<-data.frame(userID=1:30000,userName=sample(LETTERS,30000,T),productID=30001:60000,productName=sample(LETTERS,30000,T),userRate=runif(30000))
  DT2<-data.frame(productID=sample(30001:60000,500), similarproductID=sample(30001:60000,500))

  colnames(DT2)<-c("BadproductID","productID") #Do this to match the colname in DT1

  DTMerged<-merge(DT1,DT2, by="productID") #Should give you all your matches without NA's
```